# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=..) using Macaw Pod iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Macaw to parse and render an SVG file gotten from the server.

Here's the source code: https://pastebin.com/g9vUCpGX

How can I accomplish this task?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var profileBadge: SVGView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/couchdb.svg")!
        if profileBadge != nil{
            profileBadge.loadSVG(from: url)
        }
    }
}
extension SVGView {
    func loadSVG(from url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                return
            }

            guard let svgString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                return
            }

            let node = (try? SVGParser.parse(text: svgString)) ?? Group()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(node)
                self.node = node
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Answer (score 1):

You may use XIB or Storyboard.. It works using like below.

```
import UIKit
import Macaw
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var profileBadge: SVGView = SVGView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(profileBadge)

        profileBadge.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }

        let url = URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/couchdb.svg")!
        if profileBadge != nil{
            profileBadge.loadSVG(from: url)
        }
    }
}
extension SVGView {
    func loadSVG(from url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                return
            }

            guard let svgString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                return
            }

            let node = (try? SVGParser.parse(text: svgString)) ?? Group()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(node)
                self.node = node
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure out the issue. :) profileBadge should've been a UIView not UIImageView. And in the Identity Inspector, Class should've been SVGView and Module should've been Macaw.